# R Frequency Tables: prop.table does not work if all data points within variable share the outcome?

Tags: r, apply

imagine, you have the following data set:

```
df<-data.frame(read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
ID  Wine    Beer    Water   Age Gender
1   0   1   0   20  Male
2   1   0   1   38  Female
3   0   0   1   32  Female
4   1   0   1   30  Male
5   1   1   1   30  Male
6   1   1   1   26  Female
7   0   1   1   36  Female
8   0   1   1   29  Male
9   0   1   1   33  Female
10  0   1   1   20  Female"))
```

Further, imagine you want to compile summary tables that print out the frequencies of those that drink wine, beer, water.

I solved it that way.

```
con<-apply(df[,c(2:4)], 2, table)
con_P<-prop.table(con,2)
```

It works perfectly. No problem. Now, let us tweak the data set as follows: We set all entries for water to `1`.

df<-data.frame(read.table(header = TRUE, text = "

```
df<-data.frame(read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
ID  Wine    Beer    Water   Age Gender
1   0   1   1   20  Male
2   1   0   1   38  Female
3   0   0   1   32  Female
4   1   0   1   30  Male
5   1   1   1   30  Male
6   1   1   1   26  Female
7   0   1   1   36  Female
8   0   1   1   29  Male
9   0   1   1   33  Female
10  0   1   1   20  Female"))
```

If I now run the following commands:

```
con<-apply(df[,c(2:4)], 2, table)
con_P<-prop.table(con,2)
```

it gives me the following error message after the second line: `Error in margin.table(x, margin) : 'x' is not an array`! Why?

Why does it make a difference if all data points within a variable have all the same outcome? Also, what can I do to circumvent this problem? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `prop.table` uses the function `sweep` which takes an array as first argument. Since your second `con` is a list and not an array, `prop.table` will fail.

Why is your second `con` a list? Because the column `Water` has just one element and all the other columns have 2 elements. When the number of elements is different `apply` can't simplify the result to an array and gives you a list.

In the example you gave us, a safer way is to work with `lapply` instead, it will always give a list with the results:

```
con <- lapply(df, table)
con_P <- lapply(con, function(x) x/sum(x))
```

Comment: ! Another question. If my ultimate end goal is to create a barplot (by using `barplot`) then not even `con_P <- lapply(con, function(x) x/sum(x))` would not help me. Any idea what to do? Thanks

Comment: @DomB maybe it would be better to make another question, so you could explain in more details what you want.